# Meteor appcache usable for bundling app for phonegap?

Tags: cordova, meteor

Does anybody know if the bundle-impl in appcache can be used on meteor-bundle time to create a phonegap compatible bundle?

Comment: Not sure if it will really provide an answer or not, but FWIW the [Meteor Devshop 8 video](http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/10/09/meteor-devshop-8-tech-talks-interview-and-verso) includes Verso, which was published using phonegap.  "Percolate Studio delivered a stunning demo of Verso, a cross-platform mobile web app that feels native and is powered by Meteor and PhoneGap."

Comment: Watched the video, and it looks like at the 20:16 mark Tom mentions that they want to work on tackling a pre-warmed app cache, so not sure if that means they tried what you're asking or not.  It should meant that this is something Tom / Percolate are working on, so if it doesn't Just Work, they may be good to work with to make it happen. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your packaging strategy, you can use the `appcache` package with PhoneGap to cache the last loaded version of your application.

This is not relevant for PhoneGap applications where your Meteor.js project is bundled within the app.

However, for PhoneGap apps that load in the Meteor.js application at runtime, you can use the `appcache` package to cache the last loaded version of your app within the PhoneGap package. This means, following first start, your app should open and load very quickly.

Meteor.js will also hot-patch the appcache with the latest version of your codebase when you connect, so this basically means seamless, automatic app updates... Cool!

Answer (score -1):

There a several methods for integrating Meteor with Cordova. Some of them work with `appcache` and some don't. I just released a new package that makes integrating with Cordova really easy and works with `appacache` - https://github.com/andrewreedy/meteor-cordova-loader/ .. Enjoy!

Comment: The whole point of appcache is so that when that "link" does become broken the assets are stored on the client..